# How facebook mobile autentication work

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm curious to know how facebook has implemented authentication on mobile app.

The app is installed on the mobile device, then (the first time), it ask you email and password and store them. Where? In a file? Or in a sqlite db? And how facebook protect them?

The next time, the app doesn't prompt the login, so i think that user and password are sent automatically by the app. Also I read that, after the login, the facebook's api generate a token used during the request/responses between mobile and server.

Answer (score 0):

It would be this token I'm guessing that's associated with your account to allow communication between the mobile client and the facebook servers.  I doubt that your password and username are stored in a file anywhere locally but they would be stored someplace within facebook servers encrypted.

Comment: Maybe, when the user insert email and password for the first time, fb associate the user with the Device Id, at that time the device become trusted

Answer (score 0):

i believe its stored in sqlite db. because at times when i'm trying to logging in over a slow network,or if the connection is unsuccessful i get this particular error message in logcat

"sqlite code returned 0".